# What is the appropriate word in this context?

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to write down the solution to a math problem which has five separated questions, marked as (i), (ii),  (iii), (iv) and (v). At the beginning of my answer, I would like to write something like this:

> Through the following discussion, we will separately prove the properties stated in the five (...) of the proposed problem.

What would be the right word to use in (...)? Maybe *items*, or *questions*? In Spanish we have a standard word to refer to the different questions of a problem, but is there one in English too?

Comment: _I will address the different sections of the question sequentially._ But does this really need to be spelled out?

Comment: 'Through the following discussion, we will separately prove the properties stated in each of the five problems'.

Comment: Thank you, _sections_ sounds good to me. @Edwin Ashworth, you probably are right and it doesn't need to be spelled out, but it seemed a little blunt to just start answering the five questions without any introduction... Does it sound strange to start that way?

Comment: Consider calling them *parts*.

Comment: If you label your part-questions as you get to them, that is sufficient and all that is expected/usually wanted in the maths domain. I taught maths to beyond A-level.

Comment: Enumerated points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Section' is the word you are looking for. You need to use plural form 'sections'. 
Yeah, in my country it sounds strange to start that way, at least while answering mathematics.

Comment: Others have considered this too basic an answer to submit as an 'answer'.